# Django Custom model method with parameters, NON DRY

Tags: django, templatetags

After much research and trouble i came up with a non DRY solution, Hope someone can make it DRY.

All im trying to get is a calculated Price which takes a parameter and displays in the template accordingly.
i have a function **get_price** on model **vehiclecategory** which takes a parameter duration which is received from frontend forms.

## MODELS.PY

```py
class VehicleCategory(models.Model):

    CATEGORY_CHOICES=(
        ('E-Cycle', 'E-Cycle'),
        ('E-Scooter', 'E-Scooter')
    )
    
    main_category = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices= CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        width_field="width_field",
        height_field= "height_field",
        default= 'e-bike.png',
        upload_to='category')
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=250)
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=250) 
    slug =models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
   
    #GET PRICE
    def get_price(self, duration):
        for item in VehiclePrice.objects.all():
            if item.vehicle_category.title == self.title and (duration >= item.slab.start and duration <= item.slab.end):
                return item.total_price
        
    class Meta():   
        verbose_name = "Vehicle Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Vehicle Categories"


class PriceSlab(models.Model):

    start = models.IntegerField()
    end = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s ' % (self.start, self.end)



class VehiclePrice(CustomerStatus):

    help_text= "Ensure no more than 2 digits after decimal"
    vehicle_category = models.ForeignKey(VehicleCategory, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True,         related_name='vehicle_category_price')
    slab = models.ForeignKey(PriceSlab, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    net_price = models.DecimalField(help_text= help_text, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    tax_percent = models.DecimalField(help_text=help_text, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,   default=18.00)
    discount_percent = models.DecimalField(help_text=help_text,max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
    
    
    @property
    def total_tax(self):    
        tax = (self.net_price * self.tax_percent)/100
        return tax

    @property
    def get_price(self):
        total = self.net_price  + self.total_tax
        return total 

    @property
    def total_discount(self):
        discount = (self.get_price * self.discount_percent)/100
        return discount

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        total = self.get_price - self.total_discount
        
        return round(total)

    class Meta():
        unique_together=('customer_status','vehicle_category' ,'slab')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s - %s' % (self.customer_status, self.vehicle_category, self.slab)
```

## VIEWS.PY

```py
class HomeView(ListView):

    template_name = 'app/home.html'

    def get(self, request): 
        

        if request.method == "GET":
            start_date =  request.GET.get('start_date')
            end_date =  request.GET.get('end_date')

            if start_date and end_date:
                start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
                end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%d/%m/%Y").date()

                duration = (end_date - start_date).days +1
                print(duration)
                
                vehiclecategory= VehicleCategory.objects.all()
                

                context = {
                    'price1': VehicleCategory.objects.get(main_category= 'E-Cycle',    title="Sporty").get_price(duration),
                    'price2': VehicleCategory.objects.get(main_category= 'E-Cycle', title="Step-Through").get_price(duration),
                    'price3': VehicleCategory.objects.get(main_category= 'E-Cycle', title="Fatbike").get_price(duration),
                    'price4': VehicleCategory.objects.get(main_category= 'E-Scooter', title="Scooter").get_price(duration),
                   
                    'vehiclecategory1': vehiclecategory.filter(main_category= 'E-Cycle', title="Sporty"),
                    'vehiclecategory1': vehiclecategory.filter(main_category= 'E-Cycle', title="Step-Through"),
                    'vehiclecategory1': vehiclecategory.filter(main_category= 'E-Cycle', title="Fatbike"),
                    'vehiclecategory2': vehiclecategory.filter(main_category= 'E-Scooter', title="Scooter"),
                   
                    'form':CartQuantityForm(),
                    'dateform': DateForm(),
                }
            else:
                context={'dateform': DateForm(),}

        

            return render(request, self.template_name, context )
```

after the user inputs the date range, the vehicles are displayed, but when u go to the cart and come back the same page, the page refreshes as a new one. how can keep the date range values intact and render the same page as the user got first time he searched for a vehicle, so that he can add or modify the vehicles selected???

Answer (score 0):

You may put your start & end dates into your URL.

You can create 2 urls record dispatching the same view:

```py
   path(r'/prices/', HomeView.as_view())
   path(r'/prices/(?P<start>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})_(?P<end>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', HomeView.as_view())
```

Then you need to make some changes in your view:

```py
class HomeView(ListView):

    template_name = 'app/home.html'

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        start = kwargs.get('start')
        end = kwargs.get('end')

        if start is None or end is None:
            # Ask for dates & Redirect to its new url with dates.

        else:
            # Check the dates, convert them to date object & do the rest.
```

Maybe not the best solution but the first thing came to my mind is this one.

Comment: thanks.. so this solution is for the second problem right where the page gets refreshed when the user comes back to the home page?

Comment: Hmmm, I guess yes it is. I did not think that there were more than one problem. If you could give more detail about the first problem I would edit my answer.

Comment: 2nd problem. I have 2 urls(home & search) and one view and 2 different templates. on the home I get a date range search form, action of form is "search url". everything works fine.  but a) I don't get the values in the form, how would I get the values to stay in the form. b) when I proceed from the search page and want to come back to the same search page via a link from the next page  to add or edit the selection of products or dates, how can I configure the link to work?? hope im clear